# How to send message to syslog agent in plsql

Tags: oracle, plsql, acl, syslog

I want to send message to syslog in plsql.

I think it's possible via utl_tcp and ACL but have no idea how to do that.

For example, in unix, the command should be:

```
logger -p local1.info "hello word"
```

Who know how to do same with plsql code?

thank in advance

Comment: This is rather unusual. PL/SQL is a technology for user programs running within a database; syslog is for Unix sys admins several layers down. It would be a very usual case where Unix sys admins would care about high-level programmatic database activity. What is the purpose? There may be a better way to log whatever it is you're dealing with.

Comment: That being said, anything you can do with a unix command or in shell you can do from an Oracle PL/SQL program by creating an external procedure. The extproc calls a compiled C library file which in turn can either make the unix call directly or invoke a shell script in which you can do anything you want. But you have to set up the listener properly in order to not create a security hole that enables programmers to run code as oracle. Simpler, but more of a hack (not it's intended use), you can also 
use the preprocessor option of an external table to execute a shell script on the OS.

Comment: Hello Paul, Thank for your answer. Could you develop what you said more explicitly? I have not the right now to change listener property for information.

Comment: You can create an "external procedure" (lots of info on this out there, it's an old technology) but for safety sake it is best to use a separate non-privileged Unix account (not 'oracle' or anything in the 'dba' group): this non-oracle account should start it's *own* listener and register that for extprocs so that external procedure calls create a Unix process owned by that non-privileged user, rather than 'oracle'. That way bad code can't do bad things like wipe out your DB's datafiles or something. Since the listener is yours, you have all the privs you need to manage it.

Comment: But if you don't have privs to change the default listener settings, and therefore a normal application user (not a DBA or sys admin) it is questionable whether you should be trying to write *anything* to the host outside the database. You'd be better off logging to a table you own. Ext procs aren't liked by most DBAs and complicate management, especially in a RAC setup. So again, consider whether this desire to write to syslog is the right solution to your business need.

Comment: I'm a DBA and we have to push some information to syslog. This is the rules! But of course, we don't want to make some security breach to do that. It seems it's impossible in a simple way with extproc

Comment: If you are a DBA and your PL/SQL is admin-related, you could write to the instance's alert log instead by calling `sys.dbms_system.ksdwrt`. If you wanted to write to some other separate log that you define, you could use `utl_file` (after creating the appropriate directory object). Both of those options are a lot simpler than extprocs to write to syslog. I think overall my recommendation to your org is not to insist on doing something nobody else does. Use the more acceptable approaches widely used and you'll find it easier to solve problems.

Comment: I'm  thinkning dbms_system.ksdwrt is not supported so impossible to use it. Of course you right. I can put information in a file with utl_file  but not to syslog, isn't it?

Comment: Ok, where is the official documentation for dbms_system?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can send directly to native syslog protocol. However, with [syslog-ng](https://www.syslog-ng.com/technical-documents/doc/syslog-ng-open-source-edition/3.26/administration-guide/17#TOPIC-1430962) you can read (and forward) from various sources. I would try to use the `network()`, i.e. tcp source and then simply try `UTL_TCP.WRITE_LINE()` function.

Most likely it will work better with `no-parse` option. Then you can simply send just the message and all syslog related properties will be created automatically by syslog-ng.

Comment: Thank Wernfried. But we are using syslog or more precisely rsyslog. So it's interesting to do that via syslog-ng but it's not my topic.

Comment: Check the input sources of rsyslog. I would assume, they are similar to syslog-ng. Otherwise install syslog-ng, it can be used independently from rsyslog.